# Pandas dataframe non unique values of one column based on unique values of another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a `Pandas` dataframe and I want to get a list of all of the unique years for unique events. I don't care about the `DIRECTION` column, I just want a list of `DATE`'s. I don't necessarily want the `DATE`'s to be unique, because there are sometimes multiple `ID`'s for the same date, but I don't need all of the `DIRECTION`'s for the same date.

**Pandas df**

```
ID DIRECTION DATE
ABA Z 2019
ABA N 2019
ABA E 2019
ABB Z 2019
ABB N 2019
ABB E 2019
ABC Z 2020
ABC N 2020
ABC E 2020
```

**Expected Output**

`[2019, 2019, 2020]`

**Actual Output**

`[2019, 2020]`

**Current Code**

```
ids=df['ID'].unique().tolist()
dates=df['DATE'].unique().tolist()
labels, counts = np.unique(dates, return_counts=True)
```

**

```
len(counts) == 2
#I want len(counts) == 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the unique date per id, and then concatenate them into one array:

```
np.concatenate(df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].unique().values)
```

Output:

```
array([2019, 2019, 2020])
```